# Magmi import attribute_set always as "default"

Tags: import, magmi

When using Magmi the value in the column `attribute_set` is always imported with the value `default` while the values in the import file are defined as attribute_set in the backend.

Example:
The `attribute_set` value `banden` is always imported with the value `default`.

Example of the import file:

```
store   attribute_set   category_ids    sku

admin   Banden          3               BF2156516HLON
```

I tried with `_attribute_set` as wel as with `attribute_set` (with and without underscore).

Comment: This has been answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648001/magmi-product-attributes

Answer (score 0):

attribute_set is not "imported", it's only a reference value to find attributes.
here your file does not need attribute_set at all since all you can do with that few data is to update category_ids.

attribute_set is only used when creating a new product , in "update" mode, it's not used at all.

Comment: I'm not shure I understand it correctly.
I have products that use different values for attribute_set.
But if I understand it correctly it is simply not possible to import the value from the second column "attribute_set"?

Comment: in fact, it is possible to import the value for attribute_set only on non existing items. changing attribute_set for existing item is disabled in magmi yet.

Answer (score 0):

The example above is just a part of the beginning of the file. The file has 88 columns, so I only posted the first 4 columns. My problem is indeed when creating new products. There are products in the import file with the attribute_set "banden" and products with the attribute_set "runflat". So, when creating new product from the import file I also need the attribute_set value that is in the import file.

When I import a new product it gets te attribute_set "default" instead of "banden" or "runflta" as per value of the importfile.

Sorry if my english is not good.