# Magmi Product Attributes

Tags: magento, import, magmi

Problem: Imported Attribute Sets not displaying (Using Magmi Import from CSV)

I've successfully imported products and defined attribute sets for these products. However, the attribute sets are not being displayed. I'm specifying a full name for the set under _attribute_set

Am I doing something wrong? i.e.

1. In the initial import I had the set as default. In a subsequent import, I changed the values in the CSV (under attribute_set) to the new attribute set. Is this wrong or do I have to dump all the products and re-import with the correct set?
2. I'm using the full name for the attribute set. Is this wrong or should I use the ID for the set instead?
3. Am I using the incorrect column name for attribute set? or am I missing a required column name or plugin?

Please help!

Your help is greatly appreciated in advance

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is easy : magmi handles legacy dataflow headers (no underscore). Never use underscored header names if you want magmi to recognize your headers correctly.
so use **attribute_set** not _attribute_set. 
Be also careful, underscored headers are also used in newer (1.5+) import/export magento format which is **ABSOLUTELY NOT HANDLED** by magmi.